# How to stretch a node to a CGPoint

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Hello dear developers...
One of my function gets a starting point and an ending point. Both are 'CGPoint's. I want to create a a sprite node at the starting point and then, I want to stretch that node to the ending point. How can I do that? Attention I don't want to change it's position, I want to resize it until X-Axis touches the ending point. Thanks in advance...

Comment: do you want to change it over time (like SKAction) or in one go?

Comment: What is this for? Is this an object you want to scale proportionally, or is that more like a laser beam that you want to rotate and stretch only in a particular direction?